# Can't display results of mysql query

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm new to Visual Basic, I am quite proficient in php which is why I moved on to VB. I am having trouble getting data and displaying it. Here's my full code which is supposed to look in my database "game", find the row with username "kenazz" and display the username "kenazz".

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim cs As String = "Database=game;Data Source=localhost;" _
        & "User Id=root;Password="

    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(cs)

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim stm As String = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.username = 'Kenazz'"
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(stm, conn)
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While reader.Read()
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32("id") & ": " _
                & reader.GetString("username"))
        End While

        reader.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.ToString())
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you running this as command line or through a form? Also, there's nothing in the code to explain your mention of private properties or property stubs.

Comment: @EdGibbs Sorry ignore that part lol There's no form trigger, does there need to be? See edit

Comment: No, there's no need for that. I'd suggest creating a "console application" project and copying the code there. Finally, you don't explain what's going wrong: no results, bad results, compiler error, runtime error? If so, what's the *exact* output/message?

Comment: @EdGibbs There is no output at all, that's the problem :/ Is this part correct "Console.WriteLine"?

Comment: That's correct, but you won't get any output if there isn't a console. That's why I'd make sure you're on a console application - especially since, if there's an error, you're writing that to the console too. When you run a console app, it will put up a command window, output to it, and close the command window as soon as the app finishes, so also put a debug breakpoint on the `conn.Close()` so the app will pause before the command window closes.